# Firewalld without interfaces on public zone

Tags: iptables, firewall, linux-networking, firewalld, firewalld-zone

On my Oracle Cloud server, the public zone has no interfaces attached, neither does any of the other zones.

But still if I allow a port in the public zone, it does allow the traffic through.

So why is it not needed to add the adaptor (eth0 or enp0s1) to that zone?

Answer (score 0):

Probably because the `public` zone is set as the default zone. You can check that with `firewall-cmd --get-default-zone`

https://firewalld.org/documentation/zone/default-zone.html